# Degree of a multilinear product in string field theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, lie-algebra, string-field-theory

I am going through the paper $L_{\infty}\textit{ Algebras and Field Theory, O. Hohm and B. Zwiebach (2017) }$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08824) and I cannot for the life of me figure out how and why Eq(2.3) holds.
I'm copying part of the original paper here:

> In an $L_{\infty}$ algebra we have a vector space $V$ graded by a degree, which is an integer. We will typically work with elements $B_{i}\in V$ of fixed degree. The degree enters in sign factors where, for convenience, we omit the 'deg' label. Thus, for example:
> $$ (-1)^{B_{1}B_{2}}\equiv (-1)^{deg(B_{1})\cdot deg(B_{2})}. $$
> In exponents, the degrees are relevant only mod $2$. In an $L_{\infty}$ algebra we have multilinear products. In the notation used for string field theory for multilinear products are denoted by brackets $[B_{1},...,B_{n}]$ and are graded commutative
> $$[...B_{i},B_{j},...]=(-1)^{B_{i}B_{j}}[...B_{j},B_{i},...].$$
> All products are defined to be of intrinsic degree $-1$, meaning that the degree of a product of a given number of inputs is given by
> $$\boxed{\text{deg}([B_{1},...,B_{n}])=-1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{deg}(B_{i}).} \tag{2.3}$$

I cannot come to terms with the sum on the RHS, it only feels sort of intuitive but every attempt to explicitly calculate it has been cut short.

Comment: Dear @Kandrax, I am not exactly sure what your question is. The rhs of the last equation you give seems like a definition to me. They state that, by default, the product (or the bracket) is assigned a degree -1. Then, it is obvious that the total degree of the quantity built from the braket + the vectors $B_i$ should have the total degree given in the rhs. What explicit calculation did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: Dear @Ozz, what I don't get is exactly the "obvious" part. I'm more than likely missing something but why from the way I understood the text, only 1s and -1s should survive from the product. 
Should the same equation hold for $n=2$? My guess is that the product should equal "-1" in that scenario with no additional (element) degrees added.

Comment: Dear @Kandrax, the equation still holds for $n=2$. Let me try to explain why: Each vector B has, in general, a different degree. That is, not necessarily 1 or -1. For example, if $B_1$ has degree +1 and $B_2$ has degree +43, their bracket will have a degree -1+1+43=43. Now, as they also note, these degrees are only relevant modulo 2 since they only appear as exponents of (-1). With that in mind, the bracket has a degree 43mod2=1. I hope this clarifies things a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much, reading your comments now makes everything clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Eq. (2.3) can be viewed as the defining property that the [$L_{\infty}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/L-infinity-algebra)-hierarchy of brackets $[\cdot,\ldots,\cdot]$ has internal degree $-1$.
2. The $L_{\infty}$ brackets are a generalization of the [Gerstenhaber bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra) $[\cdot,\cdot]$.